# Grey ticks of whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My friend does conversations with me on whatsapp and respond to each and every message I sent to him yet grey double ticks on my messages do not turn blue. Even in the information pane of message I cannot see the "Read time" of the message. However whenever I asked him to tell me what had I sent to him he replied correctly as if he were reading. How is he able to do that? Is there any trick or my mobile's fault? I have attached an screenshot also [image]

Comment: Is he able to see double blue ticks on his part?

Comment: I am not sure I didn't asked him but if he is able to see then what does it mean?

Comment: If he's able to see them, then he may have applied a particular patch (**hideprivacy**) via an app dubbed **Lucky Patcher**. I can tell this since I'm doing so as well.

Comment: Lucky Patcher right? And you are able to see whether your messages have read or not while other people are unable to see?

Comment: Exactly, providing that you leave WhatsApp's blue ticks setting checked.

Comment: I have downloaded it. Its awsome bro! thank you so much :)

Comment: It may be awesome, but it's off-topic for the sake of this question.

Answer (score -1):

he maybe simply reading them from his notification panel and replying. 
This is in case if u guys are having short conversations ... else it might be either  1) he is using lucky patcher.
        2) he has simply unticked the blue ticks in privacy settings.

Comment: I had tried reading from notifications and replying but this also gives blueticks and yes luck patcher is good enough to hide them